# In Spark, how can I write a file on Hadoop without an RDD?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

A Spark RDD has the `saveAsTxtFile` function. However, how I open a file and write a simple string to a hadoop store?

```
val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("example")
val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "...")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "...")

val lines: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("s3n://your-output-bucket/lines.txt")
val lengths: RDD[Int] = lines.map(_.length)
lengths.saveAsTextFile("s3n://your-output-bucket/lenths.txt")

val numLines: Long = lines.count
val resultString: String = s"numLines: $numLines"
// how to save resultString to "s3n://your-output-bucket/result.txt"

sc.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do the following?

```
val strings = sc.parallelize(Seq("hello", "there"), <numPartitions>)
strings.saveAsTextFile("<path-to-file>")
```

Else you may need to look at the hadoop API to write a file and call that code explicitly from your driver.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `SparkContext` bound to `sc`:

```scala
import java.io.{BufferedWriter, OutputStreamWriter}

val hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

val outputPath = 
  new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("hdfs://localhost:9000//tmp/hello.txt")

val overwrite = true

val bw = 
  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(hdfs.create(outputPath, overwrite)))
bw.write("Hello, world")
bw.close()
```

Notes: To keep it simple there is no code to close the writer in case of an exception.

Comment: thx. can i use the "s3n://your-output-bucket/result.txt" url, instead of "hdfs://localhost:9000//tmp/hello.txt"?